# hadoop command not found even I've set the path

Tags: hadoop, hdfs, ubuntu-16.04, bigdata

I've installed single node cluster in my machine.
I am getting the error though I've set the hadoop path in bashrc file.

my bashrc file looks like below

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of `HADOOP_PREFIX` use `HADOOP_HOME`, your bashrc file should look like this

```
# -- HADOOP ENVIRONMENT VARIABLES START -- #
export JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle
export HADOOP_HOME=/home/wenky/hadoop-2.6.0-cdh5.9.0
export PATH=$PATH:$HADOOP_HOME/bin
export PATH=$PATH:$HADOOP_HOME/sbin
export HADOOP_MAPRED_HOME=$HADOOP_HOME
export HADOOP_COMMON_HOME=$HADOOP_HOME
export HADOOP_HDFS_HOME=$HADOOP_HOME
export YARN_HOME=$HADOOP_HOME
export HADOOP_COMMON_LIB_NATIVE_DIR=$HADOOP_HOME/lib/native
export HADOOP_OPTS="-Djava.library.path=$HADOOP_HOME/lib"
# -- HADOOP ENVIRONMENT VARIABLES END -- #
```